# Windows 8: Password is never accepted on first attempt

Tags: windows-8

I installed Windows 8 Pro a few weeks before it got released last year from Dreamspark and used a Microsoft outlook.com account as user account.

Since then, **every time** I boot that machine I have to type in my password twice. On the first attempt, it says my password is wrong. On the second attempt, it works.

This is so annoying. I'm not that dumb that I would misspell it every time, I rarely do that because this is a password I type about 50 times a day. So I can't be the problem. Updates are getting installed regularly, if this really is a bug then Microsoft doesn't know about it (or doesn't care).

Any ideas what could cause/how to solve this?

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if there is something strange with CAPS and/or NUM lock going on or a keyboard layout issue? Perhaps the first time you type the password, windows has not finished initializing everything. Does it work OK if you wait a couple of minutes before typing it in the first time?

Comment: dunno if it applies, but did you write any password before or any code? does keyboard buffer crap apply in this situation? (please comment)

Comment: @terdon Already tried waiting a bit, doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Znau No, my password is the first thing that I type after a fresh boot.

Comment: Does the first character you type get recognized? Try pressing a modifier key (Shift, Ctrl, etc.) before entering the password.

Comment: What happens if you type it with the visual keyboard, using the mouse? If it works, from the first try, then there's something wrong with your keyboard.

Comment: I'm going to ask the obvious and probably stupid question, but have you clicked/pressed a key at the lockscreen before putting your password in?

Comment: I would be fascinated to know what happens if you use AutoAdminLogon, thus bypassing the need to type.

Comment: I was also wondering what happens if you change the password, or logon with another account.

Comment: I'm wondering if it hasn't had enough time to finish connecting to the network in order to log in with your online account.  What about if you try using a local user account instead?  You can link the local account to your online account in order to use the store, etc.

Comment: Have you checked the input language?

Comment: I'm not sure about 8 Pro, but on Server 2012 (which is a very similar UI afaik) once you start typing a password, there's a cryptic symbol at the right of the input field.  It's actually supposed to be an eye; if you click and hold it, it unmasks the password so you can actually see what was typed.  If there's any issue with the keyboard layout, caps lock, or whatever else has been suggested above, this'll make it obvious.

Comment: In my experience the first character get lost between showing the login prompt and handling the keystrokes. You have to wait a little before actually typing your password.

Comment: I also have this problem. Checked all the obvious solutions stated above. Waited long enough for keyboard to be active, numlock is off, etc. Always fails the first time.

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue as well, and it is caused by typing your password before the Lock Screen wallpaper has fully cleared (hint: even when it looks like it's fully off-screen.. it might not be). I don't start typing until I see the password box appear, but apparently there's a delay before it will actually capture input. Hitting "shift" (or any other non-typing key) a few times usually works -- not because it helps "wake up" anything, but rather because it slows me down enough that Windows gets caught up to the user.

You can circumvent this issue by using Group Policy Editor (if available on your version of Windows) to disable the Lock Screen policy under Admin Templates -> Control Panel.

Comment: How about you provide us the full instructions in the answer itself instead of just linking to what appears to be a personal blog of some random person?  Your answer should simply provide the entire solution within it's body/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The link didn't answer the question, it provided a work-around to people who didn't like the real answer, which was "don't type so quickly; file a bug report with Microsoft". But I've changed it as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

try to logout from your administrator account and then try to login again ,see if u have to type password twice again. If not that means that you are pressing your keyboard before your computer completely turns on .

Answer (score 0):

There's a registry key to do this that I verified works in windows 8.1 Home edition:

Under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization` set dword key `NoLockScreen` to 1. File to do it automatically can be downloaded here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/134620/how-to-disable-the-lock-screen-on-windows-8-without-using-group-policy/